# Different Prices per Customer

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to have a different price to your customers?  This is mainly for wholesale where retailers would have different pricing depending on several things.  The idea is that once they login they would be able to see their price in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but it involves a few concessions on your part. Are you willing to split your inventory? Same SKU could cost N prices. So you have to split available inventory N ways.

If it is simply a retail vs wholesale price, it is much easier. Tag the customer as wholesale, and then in your theme, when a customer is tagged wholesale, you'd show off wholesale priced products, likely from some wholesale collection. If they were retail, you'd show the retail collection of products.

When you examine how Apps do customer specific pricing, you'll see other concessions you might have to make too.